# robots.txt vs google bot как померить?

Tags: seo

Google bot стал жаловаться на отображение веб-страниц на мобильных устройствах (слишком мелкий шрифт, элементы расположены слишком близко). При этом в качестве страницы он воспринимал директорию wp-content, которая отображалась в виде списка при запросе с соответствующим URL). После того как запретил обращение к данной директории в robot.txt стало поступать еще больше жалоб на то, что недоступны скрипты, картинки, css. Робот видит страницу только в в виде доступных ему директорий. Так как же ему угодить?

Comment: Sorry, помирить конечно же :(

Comment: Перестать блокировать wp-content, очевидно. И оптимизировать сайт для мобильных устройств, столь же очевидно

Comment: Содержимое wp-content со списком отображаться НЕ должно. У вас неправильно настроенный сервер, вам следует отключить отображение списка файлов в его настройках (но не блокировать wp-content)